# Synchronize two processes through network share

Tags: c#, synchronization

I'm writing a C# app. My app reads from a network share folder. This app could be running in several computers but I want that only one app at a time is reading from this share folder.

I'm thinking that I can synchronized this through creating an exclusive file with a predefined name.
Is it the best way?

How can I do this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: As long as you have write access...

Comment: yes you can lock a file or you can use another storage for access such as database.

Comment: What happens if the app crashes and leaks the file handle?

Comment: What if a disconnected computer accesses the share in "offline" mode?